# Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I am getting error while updating composer at laravel project. I'm using laravel 5.6.

While updating composer getting `Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`. I tried so many solution but nothing happen, error exists still.

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xyz.x' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `x`)

  at /erp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   App\Services\Listing\CompositionChecker::__construct()
      [internal]:0

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xyz.x' doesn't exist")
      /erp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:326

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: run this command  ``composer update``

Comment: getting error while updating the composer only

Comment: check ``.env `` file for database configuration ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all files from `bootstrap/cache` directory from root of Laravel app helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check-in your project `.env` file has or not and setup of database correctly setup.